# Using helm client on google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-console

Hello I want to use helm on google cloud console.
Tiller is already installed.

I did the following steps:

```
 wget https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.7.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Then:

```
tar zxfv helm-v2.7.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Now I can use helm within the folder helm is with:

```
./helm init --client-only
```

But I want just type helm to use it. What's needed to use it directly from cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the directory where the helm binary is placed to your $PATH, [as explained in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162134/how-to-execute-a-bash-script-without-typing). That way, next time you invoke `helm` it will try to look for a binary in the folders specified in the $PATH environment variable.

Or you can move the helm binary to one of the folders that are currently in your $PATH, like `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Yes it tried to copy to /usr/local/bin but it said permisson denied. Thanks a lot I will try the other way. I am a little bit new to linux didn't know that there also exist a path.